# Get related data from retrieved column with MAX()

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT MAX(count) FROM visits
```

With this example Query I got e.g the most active User of a Page. But with `MAX()` I can only get the maximal `count`,e.g max visits of users.

Is it possible, to retrieve the related data *(hole column where `count` came from)* to the selected `count` value, e.g the `username`?

Comment: `ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 1` It won't take into account a case if multiple users have the same maximum number of visits (?) though (and you did not mention it explicitly either)

Answer (score 2):

You could use this query:

```
SELECT visits.*
FROM   visits
WHERE  count=(SELECT MAX(count) FROM visits)
```

this query could return more than one row if multiple visits share the same maximum count.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes here whose RDBMS supports windowing, a clean solution is

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT visits.*, rank() AS r
  OVER (ORDER BY visits.count DESC)
  FROM visits) AS subquery
WHERE r=1;
```

This question is tagged mysql which doesn't have this. Ties for max are handled correctly.

Comment: I don't believe so; it appears to be on the requested features list. I don't use MySQL. Sorry. However, people tend to land on SO pages from search engines and they may be using who-knows-what. This does work with PostgreSQL, and I believe SQL Server and Oracle.